# Spring security always giving me bad credentials exception

Tags: spring-security, userdetailsservice

I am configuring spring security with annotation Version 4.0.2

Here is my SpringSecurityConfig

```
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler;

    @Autowired
    private RestAuthenticationEntryPoint restAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/admin/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
                .antMatchers("/api/teacher/**")
                .access("hasRole('ROLE_TEACHER') or hasRole('ROLE_DBA')").antMatchers("api/**")
                .access("permitAll").and().formLogin().permitAll().loginProcessingUrl("/api/login")
                .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("passowrd")
                .successHandler(successHandler).failureHandler(failureHandler).and().csrf()
                .disable().exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint);

    }
}
```

Here is my UserDetailsService

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserServiceImpl.class);

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        LOGGER.info("username " + username);
        List<GrantedAuthority> auths = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        GrantedAuthority auth = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN");
        auths.add(auth);
        LOGGER.info("auths - " + auths);
        UserDetails user = new User(username, "admin", true, true, true, true, auths);
        LOGGER.info("user - " + user);
        return user;
    }
}
```

UserService interface has no method yet

```
public interface UserService extends UserDetailsService {
}
```

I am sending post request on the url http://localhost:8080/tutor/api/login
data in post - username=admin, password=admin
where tutor is contenxt.

I am getting 401 Unauthorized exception - 
I have printed stacktrace of authentication exception in AuthenticationFailureHandler and here is exception stack trace -

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.additionalAuthenticationChecks(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:98)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:165)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:167)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:217)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Can somebody please point out what exactly i am missing.

Comment: Take a look on this Tutorial about Spring Security : https://jaxenter.com/rest-api-spring-java-8-112289.html

Answer (score 0):

It was a spelling mistake

```
passwordParameter("passowrd")
```

wrote passowrd instead of password.